# Replacing values in one column with values from a second column based on a third column

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

So I have a list of 2500 places that I've tried geocoding. Roughly 97 won't geocode. However a while ago someone went through by hand and geocoded these. I've left joind the newest list of geocoded places with the old hand-geocoded table. I'd like to replace the missing/bad geocodes with the hand-geocoded records. The data looks something like this

```
NewLat OldLat Flag
29.019 39.213 1
41.23  41.23  0
NA     38.13  1
0.00   41.29  1
```

I'd like it so that the following happens:

If the NewLat is NA or 0.00, replace the value with the OldLat.
If the record has a Flag of 1, replace with the OldLat.

The hopeful result being

```
  NewLat OldLat Flag
    39.213 39.213 1
    41.23  41.23  0
    38.13  38.13  1
    41.29  41.29  1
```

so far I have

```
df$NewLat[is.na(df$NewLat)]<-df$OldLat
```

but the second part is stumping me. I've tried

```
if("1"%in%df$Flag){df$NewLat=df$OldLat}
```

and `elseif (df$Flag =1) {df$NewLat=df$OldLat}`

and `mutate(df, df$NewLat = ifelse(df$NewLat<1.0,df$OldLat,df$NewLat))`

but nothing seems to be working.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: After receiving help I have it mostly working except that Longitude still has the initial records unmutated. Here is the code

```
# Set the working directory
setwd("C:/Users/bwhite/Desktop/Geocode")

# read in the Newest CDOE data that was geocoded in MapMarker; change missing to NA, 2521 records
MM <-read.csv("CDOE_Schools_021919_GEOCODED.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE,na.strings = c("", "NA"))

# see how many rows are missing out_county; 97 this time around
sum(is.na(MM$Out_County))

# see how many rows have a "0" for lat and long. Should match the out_county
sum(MM$NewLat<1.000)
sum(is.na(MM$NewLat))
sum(MM$NewLong <1.000 & MM$NewLong >-99.00)
sum(is.na(MM$NewLong))

# see how many bad geocode flags there are but don't include NA's, there are 150
sum(MM$Bad_Geo,na.rm=TRUE)

# Create unique ID in MM
MM$Key<-paste(MM$SCHOOL_NAME,MM$PHYSICAL_ADDRESS)

# read in the previous CDOE OpenData CSV, 2481 records
OD <-read.csv("CDPHE_CDOE_School_Locations_and_District_Office_Locations.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Create unique ID
OD$Key<-paste(OD$School_Name,OD$Address)

# Inner Join to see how many records match, 2189 records match
InnerTest<-merge(x=MM,y=OD[,c("COUNTY","OldLong","OldLat","Key")], by="Key")

# Left Outer Join the OD County/Lat/Long columns to the MM by School Code
Joined<-merge(x=MM,y=OD[,c("COUNTY","OldLong","OldLat","Key")], by="Key", all.x = TRUE)

################################################
############# COUNTY CALCULATIONS ##############
################################################

#Fill in the county values from the MM table with Out_County field
Joined$County = Joined$Out_County

# Fill in the remaining missing county values from the OD table County field
Joined$County[is.na(Joined$County)] <- Joined$COUNTY[is.na(Joined$County)]

# See how many schools are now missing County variable. #18 new schools remain to be geocoded by hand
sum(is.na(Joined$County))


################################################
############# Lat/LONG CALCULATIONS ##############
################################################

#For all bad geocodes, or for 0.00 lats, or for NA lats, fill in lat with the previous OpenData Lat 
library(dplyr)
Joined %>% 
  mutate(NewLat=ifelse(is.na(NewLat)|NewLat<1.0 &Bad_Geo==1,OldLat,NewLat))


#For all bad geocodes, or for 0.00 longs, or for NA longs, fill in long with the previous OpenData long
Joined %>% 
  mutate(NewLong=ifelse(is.na(NewLong)|NewLong=0.00 &Bad_Geo==1,OldLong,NewLong))

# See how many lats are missing now ; now there are zero!
sum(is.na(Joined$NewLat))
sum(MM$Latitude==0)

# See how many longs are missing now; There are still 97
sum(is.na(Joined$NewLong))
sum(MM$NewLong==0)

# Remove extraneous columns
Joined$Key<-NULL


# Export to Excel
?write.csv
write.csv(Joined,file="CDOE_Schools_GEOCODED_CLEANED.csv")
```

Here is the output of `dput(head(MM,15))`

```
structure(list(SCHOOL_CODE = c(2572L, 5828L, 5972L, 7296L, 8762L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), SCHOOL_NAME = c("LEGACY ACADEMY", 
"MESA VALLEY COMMUNITY SCHOOL", "MOLHOLM ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
"RED SANDSTONE ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "CHRISTIAN COMMUNITY SCHOOLS", 
"ABRAHAM LINCOLN HIGH SCHOOL", "ACADEMY CHARTER SCHOOL", "ACRES GREEN ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
"GLACIER PEAK ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ACADEMY OF CHARTER SCHOOLS", 
"FOX HOLLOW ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ACADEMY ENDEAVOUR ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
"LIBERTY MIDDLE SCHOOL", "ACADEMY INTERNATIONAL ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
"ADAMS CITY MIDDLE SCHOOL"), PHYSICAL_ADDRESS = c("1975 LEGACY CIRCLE", 
"2387 PATTERSON RD", "6000 WEST 9TH AVENUE", "551 NORTH FRONTAGE ROAD", 
"3099 F ROAD", "2285 SOUTH FEDERAL BOULEVARD", "1551 PRAIRIE HAWK DRIVE", 
"13524 NORTH ACRES GREEN DRIVE", "12060 JASMINE STREET", "11800 LOWELL BLVD", 
"6363 SOUTH WACO STREET", "3475 HAMPTON PARK DRIVE", "21500 EAST DRY CREEK ROAD", 
"8550 CHARITY DRIVE", "4451 EAST 72ND AVENUE"), PHYSICAL_CITY = c("ELIZABETH", 
"GRAND JUNCTION", "LAKEWOOD", "VAIL", "GRAND JUNCTION", "DENVER", 
"CASTLE ROCK", "LITTLETON", "BRIGHTON", "WESTMINSTER", "AURORA", 
"COLORADO SPRINGS", "AURORA", "COLORADO SPRINGS", "COMMERCE CITY"
), PHISICAL_STATE = c("CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", 
"CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO"), PHYSICAL_ZIPCODE = c(80107L, 
81505L, 80214L, 81657L, 81504L, 80219L, 80104L, 80124L, 80605L, 
80031L, 80116L, 80920L, 80016L, 80920L, 80022L), PHYSICAL_ZIPCODE_4 = c(8330L, 
1219L, 2301L, 4062L, NA, 5433L, 7900L, 2701L, 4625L, 5097L, 1098L, 
4611L, 2086L, 7360L, 1405L), PHONE = c(3036462636, 9702547202, 
3039826207, 9703282910, 9704344619, 7204235000, 3036604881, 3033877125, 
7209725940, 3032898088, 7208868700, 7192345600, 7208862400, 7192344000, 
3032895881), LOWEST_GRADE = c("Kindergarten", "Kindergarten", 
"Preschool", "Preschool", "Preschool", "9th Grade", "Preschool", 
"Preschool", "Kindergarten", "Preschool", "Preschool", "Kindergarten", 
"6th Grade", "Preschool", "6th Grade"), HIGHEST_GRADE = c("8th Grade", 
"12th Grade", "6th Grade", "5th Grade", "Preschool", "12th Grade", 
"8th Grade", "6th Grade", "5th Grade", "12th Grade", "5th Grade", 
"5th Grade", "8th Grade", "5th Grade", "8th Grade"), ORGANIZATION_CODE = c(920L, 
2000L, 1420L, 910L, 2000L, 880L, 900L, 900L, 20L, 8001L, 130L, 
1040L, 130L, 1040L, 30L), District_Name = c("ELIZABETH SCHOOL DISTRICT", 
"MESA COUNTY VALLEY 51", "JEFFERSON COUNTY R-1", "EAGLE COUNTY RE 50", 
"MESA COUNTY VALLEY 51", "DENVER COUNTY 1", "DOUGLAS COUNTY RE 1", 
"DOUGLAS COUNTY RE 1", "ADAMS 12 FIVE STAR SCHOOLS", "CHARTER SCHOOL INSTITUTE", 
"CHERRY CREEK 5", "ACADEMY 20", "CHERRY CREEK 5", "ACADEMY 20", 
"ADAMS COUNTY 14"), District_Setting = c("Remote", "Urban-Suburban", 
"Denver Metro", "Outlying Town", NA, "Denver Metro", "Denver Metro", 
"Denver Metro", "Denver Metro", "Urban-Suburban", "Denver Metro", 
"Urban-Suburban", "Denver Metro", "Urban-Suburban", "Denver Metro"
), CHARTER = c("Y", "Y", "N", "N", NA, "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N"), Type = c("Public School Physical Address ", 
"Public School Physical Address ", "Public School Physical Address ", 
"Public School Physical Address ", "Non-Public School Mailing Address ", 
"Public School Physical Address ", "Public School Physical Address ", 
"Public School Physical Address ", "Public School Physical Address ", 
"Public School Physical Address ", "Public School Physical Address ", 
"Public School Physical Address ", "Public School Physical Address ", 
"Public School Physical Address ", "Public School Physical Address "
), County = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), Out_County = c("ELBERT", "MESA", "JEFFERSON", "EAGLE", 
"MESA", "DENVER", "DOUGLAS", "DOUGLAS", "ADAMS", "ADAMS", "ARAPAHOE", 
"EL PASO", "ARAPAHOE", "EL PASO", "ADAMS"), Organization_Size = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    MatchCode = c("S80", "S80", "S80", "S80", "S80", "S80", "S90", 
    "S82", "S90", "S80", "S90", "S80", "S80", "S80", "S80"), 
    LocationCode = c("AI0", "AI0", "AI0", "AI0", "AI0", "AS0", 
    "AS0", "AS0", "AS0", "AS0", "AS0", "AS0", "AS0", "AS0", "AS0"
    ), NewLong = c(-104.627296, -108.537918, -105.11515, -106.389023, 
    -108.47805, -105.025124, -104.87014, -104.896454, -104.917328, 
    -105.034142, -104.780891, -104.761169, -104.735603, -104.764404, 
    -104.935112), NewLat = c(39.359467, 39.09177, 39.731579, 
    39.645741, 39.091736, 39.676849, 39.384583, 39.557961, 39.915554, 
    39.911575, 39.601196, 38.952129, 39.579823, 38.961929, 39.827293
    ), Bad_Geo = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_), Key = c("LEGACY ACADEMY 1975 LEGACY CIRCLE", 
    "MESA VALLEY COMMUNITY SCHOOL 2387 PATTERSON RD", "MOLHOLM ELEMENTARY SCHOOL 6000 WEST 9TH AVENUE", 
    "RED SANDSTONE ELEMENTARY SCHOOL 551 NORTH FRONTAGE ROAD", 
    "CHRISTIAN COMMUNITY SCHOOLS 3099 F ROAD", "ABRAHAM LINCOLN HIGH SCHOOL 2285 SOUTH FEDERAL BOULEVARD", 
    "ACADEMY CHARTER SCHOOL 1551 PRAIRIE HAWK DRIVE", "ACRES GREEN ELEMENTARY SCHOOL 13524 NORTH ACRES GREEN DRIVE", 
    "GLACIER PEAK ELEMENTARY SCHOOL 12060 JASMINE STREET", "ACADEMY OF CHARTER SCHOOLS 11800 LOWELL BLVD", 
    "FOX HOLLOW ELEMENTARY SCHOOL 6363 SOUTH WACO STREET", "ACADEMY ENDEAVOUR ELEMENTARY SCHOOL 3475 HAMPTON PARK DRIVE", 
    "LIBERTY MIDDLE SCHOOL 21500 EAST DRY CREEK ROAD", "ACADEMY INTERNATIONAL ELEMENTARY SCHOOL 8550 CHARITY DRIVE", 
    "ADAMS CITY MIDDLE SCHOOL 4451 EAST 72ND AVENUE")), .Names = c("SCHOOL_CODE", 
"SCHOOL_NAME", "PHYSICAL_ADDRESS", "PHYSICAL_CITY", "PHISICAL_STATE", 
"PHYSICAL_ZIPCODE", "PHYSICAL_ZIPCODE_4", "PHONE", "LOWEST_GRADE", 
"HIGHEST_GRADE", "ORGANIZATION_CODE", "District_Name", "District_Setting", 
"CHARTER", "Type", "County", "Out_County", "Organization_Size", 
"MatchCode", "LocationCode", "NewLong", "NewLat", "Bad_Geo", 
"Key"), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(head(MM,15))
structure(list(SCHOOL_CODE = c(2572L, 5828L, 5972L, 7296L, 8762L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L), SCHOOL_NAME = c("LEGACY ACADEMY", 
"MESA VALLEY COMMUNITY SCHOOL", "MOLHOLM ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
"RED SANDSTONE ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "CHRISTIAN COMMUNITY SCHOOLS", 
"ABRAHAM LINCOLN HIGH SCHOOL", "ACADEMY CHARTER SCHOOL", "ACRES GREEN ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
"GLACIER PEAK ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ACADEMY OF CHARTER SCHOOLS", 
"FOX HOLLOW ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", "ACADEMY ENDEAVOUR ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
"LIBERTY MIDDLE SCHOOL", "ACADEMY INTERNATIONAL ELEMENTARY SCHOOL", 
"ADAMS CITY MIDDLE SCHOOL"), PHYSICAL_ADDRESS = c("1975 LEGACY CIRCLE", 
"2387 PATTERSON RD", "6000 WEST 9TH AVENUE", "551 NORTH FRONTAGE ROAD", 
"3099 F ROAD", "2285 SOUTH FEDERAL BOULEVARD", "1551 PRAIRIE HAWK DRIVE", 
"13524 NORTH ACRES GREEN DRIVE", "12060 JASMINE STREET", "11800 LOWELL BLVD", 
"6363 SOUTH WACO STREET", "3475 HAMPTON PARK DRIVE", "21500 EAST DRY CREEK ROAD", 
"8550 CHARITY DRIVE", "4451 EAST 72ND AVENUE"), PHYSICAL_CITY = c("ELIZABETH", 
"GRAND JUNCTION", "LAKEWOOD", "VAIL", "GRAND JUNCTION", "DENVER", 
"CASTLE ROCK", "LITTLETON", "BRIGHTON", "WESTMINSTER", "AURORA", 
"COLORADO SPRINGS", "AURORA", "COLORADO SPRINGS", "COMMERCE CITY"
), PHISICAL_STATE = c("CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", 
"CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO", "CO"), PHYSICAL_ZIPCODE = c(80107L, 
81505L, 80214L, 81657L, 81504L, 80219L, 80104L, 80124L, 80605L, 
80031L, 80116L, 80920L, 80016L, 80920L, 80022L), PHYSICAL_ZIPCODE_4 = c(8330L, 
1219L, 2301L, 4062L, NA, 5433L, 7900L, 2701L, 4625L, 5097L, 1098L, 
4611L, 2086L, 7360L, 1405L), PHONE = c(3036462636, 9702547202, 
3039826207, 9703282910, 9704344619, 7204235000, 3036604881, 3033877125, 
7209725940, 3032898088, 7208868700, 7192345600, 7208862400, 7192344000, 
3032895881), LOWEST_GRADE = c("Kindergarten", "Kindergarten", 
"Preschool", "Preschool", "Preschool", "9th Grade", "Preschool", 
"Preschool", "Kindergarten", "Preschool", "Preschool", "Kindergarten", 
"6th Grade", "Preschool", "6th Grade"), HIGHEST_GRADE = c("8th Grade", 
"12th Grade", "6th Grade", "5th Grade", "Preschool", "12th Grade", 
"8th Grade", "6th Grade", "5th Grade", "12th Grade", "5th Grade", 
"5th Grade", "8th Grade", "5th Grade", "8th Grade"), ORGANIZATION_CODE = c(920L, 
2000L, 1420L, 910L, 2000L, 880L, 900L, 900L, 20L, 8001L, 130L, 
1040L, 130L, 1040L, 30L), District_Name = c("ELIZABETH SCHOOL DISTRICT", 
"MESA COUNTY VALLEY 51", "JEFFERSON COUNTY R-1", "EAGLE COUNTY RE 50", 
"MESA COUNTY VALLEY 51", "DENVER COUNTY 1", "DOUGLAS COUNTY RE 1", 
"DOUGLAS COUNTY RE 1", "ADAMS 12 FIVE STAR SCHOOLS", "CHARTER SCHOOL INSTITUTE", 
"CHERRY CREEK 5", "ACADEMY 20", "CHERRY CREEK 5", "ACADEMY 20", 
"ADAMS COUNTY 14"), District_Setting = c("Remote", "Urban-Suburban", 
"Denver Metro", "Outlying Town", NA, "Denver Metro", "Denver Metro", 
"Denver Metro", "Denver Metro", "Urban-Suburban", "Denver Metro", 
"Urban-Suburban", "Denver Metro", "Urban-Suburban", "Denver Metro"
), CHARTER = c("Y", "Y", "N", "N", NA, "N", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", 
"N", "N", "N", "N", "N"), Type = c("Public School Physical Address ", 
"Public School Physical Address ", "Public School Physical Address ", 
"Public School Physical Address ", "Non-Public School Mailing Address ", 
"Public School Physical Address ", "Public School Physical Address ", 
"Public School Physical Address ", "Public School Physical Address ", 
"Public School Physical Address ", "Public School Physical Address ", 
"Public School Physical Address ", "Public School Physical Address ", 
"Public School Physical Address ", "Public School Physical Address "
), County = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), Out_County = c("ELBERT", "MESA", "JEFFERSON", "EAGLE", 
"MESA", "DENVER", "DOUGLAS", "DOUGLAS", "ADAMS", "ADAMS", "ARAPAHOE", 
"EL PASO", "ARAPAHOE", "EL PASO", "ADAMS"), Organization_Size = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    MatchCode = c("S80", "S80", "S80", "S80", "S80", "S80", "S90", 
    "S82", "S90", "S80", "S90", "S80", "S80", "S80", "S80"), 
    LocationCode = c("AI0", "AI0", "AI0", "AI0", "AI0", "AS0", 
    "AS0", "AS0", "AS0", "AS0", "AS0", "AS0", "AS0", "AS0", "AS0"
    ), NewLong = c(-104.627296, -108.537918, -105.11515, -106.389023, 
    -108.47805, -105.025124, -104.87014, -104.896454, -104.917328, 
    -105.034142, -104.780891, -104.761169, -104.735603, -104.764404, 
    -104.935112), NewLat = c(39.359467, 39.09177, 39.731579, 
    39.645741, 39.091736, 39.676849, 39.384583, 39.557961, 39.915554, 
    39.911575, 39.601196, 38.952129, 39.579823, 38.961929, 39.827293
    ), Bad_Geo = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_), Key = c("LEGACY ACADEMY 1975 LEGACY CIRCLE", 
    "MESA VALLEY COMMUNITY SCHOOL 2387 PATTERSON RD", "MOLHOLM ELEMENTARY SCHOOL 6000 WEST 9TH AVENUE", 
    "RED SANDSTONE ELEMENTARY SCHOOL 551 NORTH FRONTAGE ROAD", 
    "CHRISTIAN COMMUNITY SCHOOLS 3099 F ROAD", "ABRAHAM LINCOLN HIGH SCHOOL 2285 SOUTH FEDERAL BOULEVARD", 
    "ACADEMY CHARTER SCHOOL 1551 PRAIRIE HAWK DRIVE", "ACRES GREEN ELEMENTARY SCHOOL 13524 NORTH ACRES GREEN DRIVE", 
    "GLACIER PEAK ELEMENTARY SCHOOL 12060 JASMINE STREET", "ACADEMY OF CHARTER SCHOOLS 11800 LOWELL BLVD", 
    "FOX HOLLOW ELEMENTARY SCHOOL 6363 SOUTH WACO STREET", "ACADEMY ENDEAVOUR ELEMENTARY SCHOOL 3475 HAMPTON PARK DRIVE", 
    "LIBERTY MIDDLE SCHOOL 21500 EAST DRY CREEK ROAD", "ACADEMY INTERNATIONAL ELEMENTARY SCHOOL 8550 CHARITY DRIVE", 
    "ADAMS CITY MIDDLE SCHOOL 4451 EAST 72ND AVENUE")), .Names = c("SCHOOL_CODE", 
"SCHOOL_NAME", "PHYSICAL_ADDRESS", "PHYSICAL_CITY", "PHISICAL_STATE", 
"PHYSICAL_ZIPCODE", "PHYSICAL_ZIPCODE_4", "PHONE", "LOWEST_GRADE", 
"HIGHEST_GRADE", "ORGANIZATION_CODE", "District_Name", "District_Setting", 
"CHARTER", "Type", "County", "Out_County", "Organization_Size", 
"MatchCode", "LocationCode", "NewLong", "NewLat", "Bad_Geo", 
"Key"), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** to move the answer after expected output was added to the front:

```
 df %>% 
      mutate(NewLat=ifelse(is.na(NewLat)|NewLat==0 |Flag==1,OldLat,NewLat))

      NewLat OldLat Flag
    1 39.213 39.213    1
    2 41.230 41.230    0
    3 38.130 38.130    1
    4 41.290 41.290    0
```

**Original::**

Hopefully I understood the logic:
Try:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(NewLat=ifelse(is.na(NewLat)|NewLat==0 &Flag==1,OldLat,NewLat))
```

Result:

```
   NewLat OldLat Flag
1 29.019 39.213    1
2 41.230 41.230    0
3 38.130 38.130    1
4  0.000 41.290    0
```

Perhaps this?

```
df %>% 
  mutate(NewLat=ifelse(is.na(NewLat)|NewLat==0 |Flag==1,OldLat,NewLat))

  NewLat OldLat Flag
1 39.213 39.213    1
2 41.230 41.230    0
3 38.130 38.130    1
4 41.290 41.290    0
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I realized I had a typo in my question and also had not shown the expected output. I've edited my post accordingly.

Comment: When I run this code I get the following error:  Error: unexpected '=' in:
"df %>%

Comment: Please load `dplyr` and replace `df` with your dataset's name

Comment: Yep sorry I was editing the df for clarify here. datset is named Joined.   Error: unexpected '=' in:
"Joined %>% 
  mutate(Joined$Latitude="

Comment: In  `dplyr` logic using the pipe(`%>%`) doesn't need usage of `$`. So we simply do as shown in the answer.

Comment: Thanks I'm not getting any errors, but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm not sure about the piping? There aren't really any NA's in my data, they're all 0.000 or some lat that is inaccurate. I have the NA statement in there as a catch-all just in case. But it seems like it's not working because the NA pipes directly into the 0? It's if any of those conditions are true (NewLat=NA,NewLat=0, Flag=1) then fill in with the old lat.

Comment: Please show what code you've used to do the manipulations. It worked fine for me when I looked at this question with the provided data. You should use part two of the answer not one. @BenW check the edit(same answer just moved it to the top). What do you mean by " NA pipes directly into the 0'?

Comment: I have attached the code I'm using in the original post under the "EDIT" section. The latitude seems to be working now but the longitude variable isn't mutating. I think that is because while my latitude values are all below 1 (because the lat is positive in the geography I'm working in), the Longitude is all either 0.00 or in the -100 degrees long.  Re: my piping statement I misunderstood. I thought the code was piping a series of subsets. E.g. find all the NA's, then select from those records which are 0's, then select from those records which have a bad flag, then mutate.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no access to the data. You can edit again to copy and paste the output of `dput(head(MM,15))` to the question. @BenW you need to use `==` not `=` here `NewLong=0.00` in `mutate(NewLong=ifelse(is.na(NewLong)|NewLong=0.00 &Bad_Geo==1,OldLong,NewLong))` Also not sure how you want to deal with the negatives.

Comment: I have edited to include the dput(head(MM,15)) output. The Bad_Geo flag should take care of negative longitudes that aren't right. When my geocoding software can't geocode it fills the value in with 0.0000 so I thought the NewLong==0 would account for this which is perplexing. Thanks again for all of your help.

Comment: So negatives should turn to positive?

Comment: Longitude negatives that are wrong will be replaced with different negatives. zeros should turn to negatives. For Latitudes positives were replaced with different positives and zeros should turn to positives.

Comment: I'm sorry this is more complex than I imagined(mainly because I need access to the second dataset and need to examine everything). However, why not just tweak the mutate statement and get the desired output? I'm sorry maybe someone else can help(again, they'll need access to both datasets). You'll have to add a dput of the second data. However, I did answer the original question.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide expected output so not sure if this is right, but my understanding is that you want three rows to be replaced. You can also use `dplyr::if_else` instead of `base::ifelse` for faster, type-stable output.

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- read_table2(
"NewLat OldLat Flag
29.019 39.213 1
41.23  41.23  0
NA     38.13  1
0.00   41.29  0"
)
tbl %>%
  mutate(NewLat = if_else(is.na(NewLat) | NewLat == 0 | Flag == 1, OldLat, NewLat))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>   NewLat OldLat  Flag
#>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1   39.2   39.2     1
#> 2   41.2   41.2     0
#> 3   38.1   38.1     1
#> 4   41.3   41.3     0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've gone back and edited my statement to show the expected output.